# WPF IDATAError no showing when control becomes visible

Tags: wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a weird issue with the ErrorTemplate.  I created a WPF MVVM application.  I am using a ErrorTemplate and the IDataError interface to show errors.  On my form I have some controls that are collapsed in a stack panel. When I show the controls the error template is not showing but the error functionality is working because the user can't save the record.  Does anyone know how I can refresh the UI or get the error template to show?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you use an adorner for your error template? if so try

```
<AdornerDecorator>
   <YourStackPanel/>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

Comment: Yes I use a adorner in my error template.  Didnt show up up.  If I select a value then select a value that is an error the UI will refresh and the error display will show up.  It is only the first time when I go into the form make the control visible by dataTrigger assocated with the control. It is like the validation is happending before the control is visible so it doesnt apply the error template?

Comment: does the AdornerDecorator help? Can you post some sample code to get this behavior?